# Pandas time series resampling with month and with group by column

Tags: python, pandas

How to resample a dateindex with month and group by one column and aggregate mean of another column.

Example of dataframe:

```
                bts_name    duration
cleareddate     
2019-01-19  1002_NUc_Marathalli 95
2019-01-21  1002_NUc_Marathalli 188
2019-02-11  1002_NUc_Marathalli 1332
2019-04-12  1002_NUc_Marathalli 940
2019-01-11  1003_IU2_Munnekolalu 73
```

I am trying to with frequency month and group by `bts_name` and `sum` the duration of each month.

Comment: Can you clarify the "resample a dateindex with month"? Do you wish to sample one item per month randomly from all the items in that month? Or do you wish to groupby both month and `bts_name`? It might help to provide an expected output with your question.

Comment: the output should be group by bts_name and month (in cleareddate) and sum the duration using  resampling

Comment: Again your use of 'resampling' is not clear. Resampling would usually refer to a bootstrap styled technique but then the 'sum' aggregate would make little sense. I will submit an answer but just comment if that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: can you show us how the output df should look like? Thanks

Comment: nick , i want to know where the resampling technique can be used to get my desired out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reset_index` to set the `cleareddate` field as a column in your dataframe. I'd create a new column with month and then you can perform a straightforward `groupby` on that.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['month'] = df.cleareddate.dt.month
df.groupby(['month','bts_name']).agg('sum').duration
```

Notes:

1. I have assumed that the index is of type datetime. If this is not the case then add `df.cleareddate = pd.to_datetime(df.cleareddate)` line after the `reset_index` line.
2. Note that months in two different years will be grouped as the same. Do you need to groupby year as well? If so, add another column for year and add that term to your groupby column

---

**EDIT:**
After discussion in comments with @sriman I have included another way of achieving the above with the pandas [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method.

```
# your data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bts_name': ['1002_NUc_Marathalli','1002_NUc_Marathalli',
                 '1002_NUc_Marathalli','1002_NUc_Marathalli',
                 '1003_IU2_Munnekolalu'],
    'duration': [95,188,1332,940,73]
}, index=pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-19','2019-01-21',
                         '2019-02-11','2019-04-12','2019-01-11']))


# solution
def resample(group):
    return group.resample('M').sum()

result = df.groupby('bts_name').apply(resample)

# result
print(result)

                                 duration
bts_name                                 
1002_NUc_Marathalli  2019-01-31       283
                     2019-02-28      1332
                     2019-03-31         0
                     2019-04-30       940
1003_IU2_Munnekolalu 2019-01-31        73
```

Comment: Thanks, it will work, is there any way to do using resampling method

Comment: Ah I think I see what you are referring to. Is it that you'd like to use this method here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html? I am sure I can add something to the above solution if that is the case.

Comment: Let me know if the edit is what you had in mind? You can always 'reset_index()' to get the bts_name and date fields out of the index and back into columns.

Comment: with your help i did like this df1.groupby('bts_name').resample('M').sum(), it is working but it is taking some time for nearly 1.2 Lakh records